# Safest way to create MS Excel file (xlsx) from Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, ms-office, spreadsheet

I know that Microsoft Excel has some notable limitations when it comes to opening arbitrary spreadsheets. Occasionally the following errors/warnings will occur:

> We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

> Errors were detected in file 'filename.xlsx'
> Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded

Google Sheets, LibreOffice, and Apple Numbers tend to be much more reliable. However, I have end-users that prefer using Excel, and they need to be able to trust the data they're looking at in the spreadsheets I produce for them.

These spreadsheets have multiple sheets and are produced by code resembling the following:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(f"{filename}.xlsx") as writer:
  for sheet in sheets:
    data = pd.DataFrame(...)
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"{sheet}")
  writer.save()
```

I previously fixed a problem with long sheet names (since MS has a limit of 31 characters), and the error went away, but the errors started cropping up again recently, with no apparent change to the code or data content.

I dug into the Excel XML directories to see if anything was missing, but all I could really ascertain was some minor formatting differences (e.g. default fonts or column widths), and a difference in XML schema -- the contents of the spreadsheet after saving a "recovered" workbook were essentially identical. That said, I would rather not tell these end-users "don't worry, the data is *probably* fine."

This leads me to my question: What is the safest way to produce Excel files from Python? Ideally, I imagine a spreadsheet writer that defaults to the MS Excel constraints, so any potential errors or warnings are produced at runtime when the file is created. Is there a better, safer Excel writer than Pandas? Is there a way to ensure Pandas produces a sheet in such a way that the end-users can avoid these errors and have confidence in the file contents?

Comment: You could always not rely on an XML writer at all, and automate Excel via COM (`win32com`). Then you would be sure that the resulting xlsx is valid (at least for the version of Excel you are using).

Comment: Would that require I generate the Excel sheet from a Windows machine? Or at least have Excel installed on the machine? This is a cloud service running on linux that's generating the document.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it would.

Answer (score 0):

With some more research I was able to learn that Pandas sets the default writer to openpyxl ***unless XlsxWriter is installed***.

After running `pip install XlsxWriter` it started producing a spreadsheet without erroring in Excel.

It's maybe worth noting, for posterity's sake, that the issue arose immediately after upgrading from python3.6 to python3.7.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this still may not be "the safest way" to create an MS Excel file from python, but it satisfied my needs (at least for now). If an answer to the overarching question is provided, that should be the accepted answer.